# Cannot ssh to google cloud instance

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

I'm newbie for GCP and I need your help which this is the step I had made.
(1) I setup google cloud firewall rules to allow ssh on port 22 and I can ssh to my instance, CentOS7, correctly.
(2) When I connect to my instance, I run some firewall script and after that I cannot ssh to my instance anymore. It seem that script block ssh port even I enable it in the VPC Network > Firewall rules.
(3) Now I cannot connect to my instance including Open in browser window in the SSH menu on gcp console.

Is there any solution to connect my instance? Please help.

Thank in advance.
Bom

Comment: See my answer here ,I hope it will give you an idea. You can always revert changes on your VM using metadata when you lose your SSH access to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64706966/cannot-connect-via-ssh-to-gcp-instance/68164716#68164716change

Answer (score 1):

You probably change block ssh port by changing firewall configuration inside VM.

So you can consider 2 options :

1) Recreate VM if no sensitive data, or not too much work spent for the existing setup.

2) Detach Boot disk and reuse it on another instance, to change the configuration files of firewal.

check [Official Docs - Use your disk on a new instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#move_boot_disk) for that:

```
gcloud compute instances delete $PROB_INSTANCE
    --keep-disks=boot

gcloud compute instances create new-instance
    --disk name=$BOOT_DISK,boot=yes,auto-delete=no

gcloud compute ssh new-instance
```

Hope it will help you.